# Stop slide when it reaches the last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

How can the slide be stopped when the last slide is reached in Owl Carousel? I have done it on `click` function using the below code. Now, I want to achieve the same when the last slide is reached

```
$(".btn-skip").click(function () {
    owl.data('owlCarousel').reinit({
        touchDrag: false,
        mouseDrag: false
    });
    owl.trigger('owl.jumpTo', 2);
});
```

Comment: I have moved the problem description to the top and have rewritten the sentences a bit. It is better to have the problem description first before the code. I have also removed the library name from the title as it is not required due to presence of the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Add the option afterAction to your owl init.

```
owl.owlCarousel({
      afterAction : afterAction
  });
```

Then, on the function declared on afterAction, evaluate if owlItems.length its equal to the current owl item plus the visible items.

```
function afterAction(){
    //Get an array of items from the variable visibleItems, then get the length of that array
    var numOfVisibleItems = this.owl.visibleItems.split(',').length();
    if(this.owl.currentItem + numOfVisibleItems == this.owl.owlItems.length){
       //Here the code you want to do after the owlCarousel reach its end
    }
}
```